# How to count the number of instances of a certain process by canonical path (with arguments)?

Tags: ps

Let's say I run the following commands:

```
sleep 500
/bin/sleep 500
sleep 30
```

What I'm interested is, how to count the number of instances of the sleep program, with certain arguments (in this case the only argument is `500`).

So in the example above, if I count the number of instances of `/bin/sleep 500`, it should return 2.

I tried this: `pgrep -xfc '/bin/sleep 500'`, but since it exactly matched the argument in the parenthesis, `sleep 500` isn't counted.

Comment: Are you running a system with a `/proc` filesystem? That makes it easier to find the pathname of each process's executable.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, I am

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you can go with:

```
pgrep -fc 'sleep 500'
```

It matches both `/bin/sleep 500` and `sleep 500`.

Or if you want to be more precise:

```
pgrep -fc 'sleep 500$'
```

Answer (score 3):

On GNU system:

```
$ ps --no-header -C sleep -o args | grep -Ec ' 500( |$)'
2
```

Answer (score 2):

On systems that support a Linux-like `/proc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# != 2 ]
then
    echo usage: "$0" pathname commandline_regexp
    exit 1
fi
cd /proc
for p in [0-9]*
do
    exe=$(readlink $p/exe 2>/dev/null)
    if [ "$exe" = "$1" ] &&
        cat $p/cmdline 2>/dev/null | tr '\0' ' ' | grep -q -- "$2"
    then
        echo match $p
    fi
done
```

example:

```
$ sleep 500&
[3] 18280
$ sleep 600&
[4] 18281
$ ./rpgrep /bin/sleep '.*sleep 500 $'
match 18280
$ ./rpgrep /bin/sleep '.*sleep.*00'
match 18280
match 18281
```

Notes:

- the `2>/dev/null` and the separate `cat` process are used to cope with the possibility that processes may disappear while the script is running.